# Laggy scrolling in UITextView while a CABasicAnimation is running

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, core-animation

I've implemented a simple animation in my app. I achieve the animation by cross-fading between four image frames using a `CABasicAnimation` that has a from and to value set to `(id)(myimage.CGImage)`. The animation is on its own CALayer but while scrolling a pop-up UITextView in its own small subview, the text scrolling is very jerky during a frame blend, and also pauses the animation while scrolling. Would putting the animation in its own thread alleviate the problem or is this simply to do with a complex operation being done by Core Animation?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I went ahead and added the animation to a separate thread but it doesn't seem to make anything smoother. Am I missing something? I guess my question now is can UI animations be sent to a separate thread or do they just always run in the main thread?

Comment: Since I've seen a similar problem and want this question to be answered I'm offering a bounty.

Comment: +1 Got a similar problem, hope there are good answers.

Comment: Use the Core Animation instrument to determine what's happening on the text layer.  Perhaps something you're doing is causing it to get rendered off-screen and hence slower.  Also have you tried using the new(ish) block methods for animation?

Comment: Thanks arrtchiu, I'll try this now and see whats happening. Never thought of using instruments to measure it!

Comment: I've changed it from a CABasicAnimation to a UIView block animation and it locks scrolling in my subview for the duration of the animation. Checked it out in the Core Animation instrument and nothing is being rendered offscreen etc. CPU is being used most on png_read_filter_row and gzopen (30% and 20% respectively). However, I cant check FPS since Instruments is counting frames upwards from 0 (not like games tend to display, which is say 150 down to 75 while rendering complex objects). Getting this animation playing and being able to interact with the UI is central to the whole app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send UI animations to a separate thread but any actual updates to the application's UI are always handled/drawn by the main thread.  So in that sense I think adding additional threads is not going to help, particularly if you have tried that already and it still does not give acceptable results.

The only thing I can think of that might help would be to use OpenGL to render your animation instead of Core Animation.  That will pull a complete layer of abstraction out of the picture, and should speed things up quite a bit as a result.  Of course, it will also likely take a lot more code to accomplish the same thing, so there is certainly a trade-off to be made.

Comment: Well, after looking at it from almost every angle and trying to make this work I think its safe to assume nobody really has any answer to it. Guess I'll just have to rethink the app and remove the UITextView. Bit annoyed Apple doesn't have a solution to this.